# Use Raspberry Pi as audio output device for iMac?

Tags: linux, macos, usb, audio, hdmi

So, I have been having issues with audio on macOS Sierra (the CoreAudio daemon randomly fails to work with analogue output, i.e. 3.5mm out jack.). I've got a Raspberry Pi 2 model B+ that I've already replaced several peripherals with, and I'm wanting to add audio output to that list.

Here's the general concept I'm trying to achieve: Connect the Raspberry Pi to my iMac via USB, and configure it such that I can select the Raspberry Pi as an audio output device in the Sound Preferences Panel. Then I want all output sent to the Pi via USB to either get piped through it's 3.5mm jack to a set of external speakers, or through it's HDMI port to my external display's speakers. While I can perform the second half of this from the Raspberry Pi itself rather easily, I haven't the slightest as to how I should go about actually using the Pi as an output device on the iMac. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how one might go about doing this?

Comment: You're better off fixing whatever is causing the CoreAudio daemon to crash or getting a cheap USB sound card online. You can get one for less than 10 bucks. Way easier than turning your Pi into a sound card IMO.

Comment: @Afzal I realize my idea seems quite convoluted, but the issue is not fixable, its caused by incompatibility between my sound chip and CoreAudio. USB output devices work fine despite the issue. However I don't own any USB speakers or headphones, and have no money to spend on a pair. I am aware it will likely be quite a bit of work to set up, but I'm more than okay with that. I enjoy creating bodges for issues (its how I fix all my problems with machines), the only real problem is that I don't know how to register something as an output device in macOS.

Comment: I am not even sure if the RPi can do that to begin with, and I haven't come across anyone who has tried it. So I hope you know how to code.

Comment: @Afzal I know C/++ 11, and Bash scripting. That should be enough for low level Unix/Linux communication. In fact the idea of someone owning a Pi in the first place, let alone one they use as a peripheral substitute, but not knowing how to code seems a bit silly to me. It is an all-purpose imbedded computer after all, I don't think someone who doesn't know how to code would have much use for it, outside of perhaps as a more convenient laptop alternative.

Comment: You should be reading on the Core Audio API and how USB audio cards work. Even though the RPi after all has a much more powerful (RISC) processor, I doubt it allows USB to TRSS output (without a delay). And last time I checked audio is based on PWM so expect potato quality at best. Alternatively, you get an extension board that will act as a low-key soundcard, with the appropriate transistors soldered on (and maybe a headphone AMP). You can also use the I²S bus as input, in that case you'd probably need to wire up the appropriate USB pins. All of these will give you a delay as you need...

Comment: ...some sort of a recording software (something compatible with the incoming Core Audio signal) that output via the analog TRSS. You probably need some help from a audio hardware engineer to even start working on a hardware-level driver for the Pi's SoC. I am not sure how much info you get on this, as these are usually proprietary. I don't remember if the Broadcam's VideoCore blobs had anything in particular for reading digital audio off another digital device (I haven't used on in 3 years now) but you should also look through those drivers and see if there is a shortcut for the audio.

Comment: Should be a fun project. But you will most likely need additional components, that maybe expensive if not bought in bulk. Definitely a lot easier if you bought a USB soundcard just for the purpose of reverse engineering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could setup your Pi to act as an A2DP receiver, or possibly set it up to do PulseAudio over WiFi too.

Bluetooth A2DP
https://www.instructables.com/id/Turn-your-Raspberry-Pi-into-a-Portable-Bluetooth-A/

PulseAudio over WiFi

https://partofthething.com/thoughts/multi-room-audio-over-wi-fi-with-pulseaudio-and-raspberry-pis/

(P.s. I know it’s a late response, but could help other people...)